# Glare node Final Render is not same with Viewport Render Glare

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glare

Final render of my scene not showing glare node correctly same with viewport render,
[image]

Here's my look viewport render with simple glare composition.
And here'e the result:[image]

can someone help me or i do something wrong connect the cable?